# Conditionally displaying button

Tags: android, android-layout

I know how to enable/disable a button defined in a layout XML after finding it:

```
  testBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.test);
```

But other than conditionally loading layouts, is there a way to tell in my code "Use that layout XML, but don't load the button defined there"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To set a View's visibility in Xml, use the android:visibility attribute.

The following sets the button visibility to gone. When set to gone Android will not show the button and not include it's size during layout calculation.

```
<Button android:id="@+id/mybutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello" 
            android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Setting android:visibility="invisible" will not show the button, but include it during layout calculation.

```
<Button android:id="@+id/mybutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello" 
            android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

To programmatically show the button in code you call the setVisibility() method.

```
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.thebuttonid);
btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //View.GONE, View.INVISIBLE are available too.
```

Comment: Your assumption is correct - I don't want it rendered as part of the layout. I want to control this dynamically in the code, what is the API method to do that?

Comment: Thank you so much. You just saved the life of a toddler in the Android world. :)