# Hidden disabled button and checkboxes

Tags: android, checkbox, hidden

I need some help with a small code.
Basically I have a button and some generated checkboxes (don't know how many). The button should be hidden and disabled as long as no check-box is checked. When one or more check-boxes are checked the button should be shown and enabled .
How can I do this?

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: I thought this looked familiar when I answered. Why did you re-post (with even less of a post)? Did my answer on your first post not work?

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a counter variable

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    int counter = 0;

    //onCreate() and other code
```

then set an `onCheckedChangedListener()` on your `CheckBoxes` and increment/decrement the value based on if the box was checked

```
onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
{
    if (isChecked)
    {
        counter++;
    }
    else
    {
        counter--;
    }
    /* if (counter > 0)
          change visibility
    */
}
```

Obviously you cannot copy/paste this code but should give you a pretty good idea.

[OnCheckedChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.html)

[setVisibility()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29)

Answer (score 1):

would be something like this?

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
LinearLayout idLayoutThisXml;
Button btn;


public boolean verifyChecked(){
    idLayoutThisXml = (LinearLayout) findViewById(idCadastro.linearLayout);
    for (int i = 0; i < idLayoutThisXml.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = idLayoutThisXml.getChildAt(i);
        if(v instanceof CheckBox){
            if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(idMain.button);
    if(verifyChecked()){
        btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else{
        btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

putting in an example ...

XML file:

```
<CheckBox android:id="@+idMain/check1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<CheckBox android:id="@+idMain/check2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<CheckBox android:id="@+idMain/check3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+idMain/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

Activity:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
LinearLayout idLayoutThisXml;
Button btn;


public boolean verifyChecked(){
    idLayoutThisXml = (LinearLayout) findViewById(idMain.layout);
    for (int i = 0; i < idLayoutThisXml.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = idLayoutThisXml.getChildAt(i);
        if(v instanceof CheckBox){
            if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(idMain.button);
    if(verifyChecked()){
        btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else{
        btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

}

so I have a layout that has children of type CheckBox, and testing will all CheckBox llinearLayout, meet at least one marked. the button becomes visible.

Comment: Why do you have 3 answers and at least two appear to be the same? And one I don't know what it is

Comment: you need to have a well-defined XML with an id for LinearLayout, enter how many you want in your CheckBoxs LinearLayout, you can also enter via Activity.
to check a CheckBox checked, you use the method verifyChecked (). Here you just need to know the id of LinearLayout in your XML and obviously all your CheckBox should be within the LinearLayout. Because the method returns true if there is at least one marked checkBox inside the LinearLayout.
In OnCreat method, I just check if the method return verifyChecked (.) If true, at least one checkBox is active, change the button visible.
Get it?

Comment: basically the method verifyChecked () traverses all the children of LinearLayout and every time a child is an instance of a checkBox it checks whether that child is marked. if it is checked it returns TRUE. ok?

Comment: in my example XML file is incomplete. lack the LinearLayout which would be the father of all the components that I put in the XML, as the 3 CehckBoxs and button. Basically what you need to change the XML is put LinearLayout and an associated ID in it, and add CheckBoxs that LinearLayout. Activity in now, you only need to reference the ID method in LinearLayout verifyChecked () and onCreate () you need to reference the id of the button that you created in XML.
In verifyChecked () you do not need to know how CheckBoxs there because it runs throughout the LinearLayout to find CheckBoxs...

Answer (score 0):

`myButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

And then, in the `CheckBox`'s `OnClickListener`, do `myButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Answer (score 0):

Set the button visibility to invisible

```
<Button android:id="@+id/mybutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello" 
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

then call

```
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.thebuttonid);
btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //View.GONE, View.INVISIBLE are available too.
```

When conditions are met. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

[Conditionally displaying button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489286/conditionally-displaying-button)

Answer (score 0):

you have a check box in the XML ok? handle the checkBox in activity with

```
CheckBox c = (CheckBox) findViewById (idThisCheckBoxInXml)
```

and an

```
if (c.isActivated ()) {
    botao.setVisibility (View.INVISIBLE) or botao.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE)
}
```

would be something like this? excuse my bad english ...

Comment: Wow. Not to be a jerk about English not being your first language, but I'm genuinely not sure what you're trying to say. Maybe it would be clearer if you posted some well-formatted code? To make some lines a block of code, put four spaces at the beginning of each line.

Comment: put a little code example now. where the numbers of independent checkBox, leave checking one by one until you find one checkBox checked or not. meet it will make the button appear if not left button invisible